# Javascript not working when import bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement this search bar into my webpage: https://github.com/jeffersonRibeiro/jquery-simpleSelect
but it does not seem to work when I import bootstrap.

I tried to see if I was importing things in incorrectly, but nothing seems to work. The only time the search bar would actually work is if I comment out the bootstrap import

The imports I am using are just from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/. Just linking the Bootstrap stylesheet appears to not make it work and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Here is the html file:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#segment').simpleSelect();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple select with search</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="simpleSelect.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="segment" name="segmentation">   
                <option data-defaultSelected>Select</option>
                <option>JAVASCRIPT</option>
                <option>PHP</option>
                <option>BRAZIL</option>
                <option>CANADA</option>
                <option>MEAN</option>
            </select>
    
            <!-- <input type="submit"/> -->
        </form>
```

Javascript: https://github.com/jeffersonRibeiro/jquery-simpleSelect/blob/master/src/js/simpleSelect.js

CSS: https://github.com/jeffersonRibeiro/jquery-simpleSelect/blob/master/src/css/simpleSelect.css

The problem occurs when I uncomment the link to the bootstrap stylesheet

Comment: Let's start with telling us what errors you're getting in the browser's console. Then, how about a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: Please show us exactly how you have this coded in code examples posted to this site.

Comment: Any ideas? Still stuck

Answer (score 1):

`./` in URLs means current directory.

So change `<script src="./src/js/simpleSelect.js"></script>` to access the correct directory.

And to run jQuery functions they need to be wrapped in either function or document.ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#segment').simpleSelect();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I placed them all into a folder and changed the way I linked them, but that doesn't appear to be the problem. I already tried using document.ready, but it doesn't work either

Comment: So the HTML is in the same folder as the javascript and CSS for simpleselect?

Comment: Yep, the search bar works with the the bootstrap import commented out, but if it's not then it doesn't work. I don't think the problem is due to accessing the correct directory since it does work until adding the bootstrap import.